# Implement UITabViewController with JASidePanelViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabview, jasidepanels

I am implementing`JASidePanel` with`UITabViewController` but I have some problem to implement.

Currently I have Category view controller with `UITabView`

[image]

After sliding shows category like this

[image]

but I want to slide only one`viewcontroller` not `UITabViewController`.

here is my code in`Baseviewcontroller` which is subclass of`JASidePanelViewController`

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.leftButtonForCenterPanel;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];

  }

  -(void) awakeFromNib
  {
   [self setRightPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CategoryViewController"]];
   [self setCenterPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabVC"]];

  }
```

Appreciate for help

Answer (score 0):

Use MMDrawerController is very easy to integrate.

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Answer (score 0):

```
   //first of all create tab bar and four navigation controller
    IBOutlet UIView *TabbarView;
    UINavigationController* childNavCtrl1;
    UINavigationController* childNavCtrl2;
    UINavigationController* childNavCtrl3;
    UINavigationController* childNavCtrl4;
    UINavigationController* childNavCtrl5;


viewDidLoad{
FavouriteVC * objFav = [[FavouriteVC alloc] init];
objFav.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
childNavCtrl1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mRiviHomeVC];
childNavCtrl1.navigationBarHidden = YES;

//same do for rest of three view controller 


now whenever user tap on any tab bar 


[self.view addSubview:childNavCtrl1.view] ;// for this u need to check condition when u need to show which view controller
```